# PHP Class with properties that has objects be accessible to these objects

Tags: php, oop

I have a main php class such as this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function __construct()
    {
       $this->a = new \SomeClass();
       $this->b = 'some string';
    }
}
```

is there a way the class which is stored in the `$a` (`SomeClass`) property can access the `$b` value which is actually a property which is stored in the class that initiated `$a` (`MyClass`) ?

Comment: You would have to pass the MyClass object to SomeClass by sending `$this` in the constructor or setting it after the object is created.  You then would need to store MyClass as a property if you intend to use any where else in SomeClass after it is instantiated.

Comment: edit complete, i hope its clearer now.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg thats what I had in mind but I thought there might be a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function __construct()
    {
      $this->a = new \SomeClass($this);
      $this->b = 'some string';
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    public $mc;

    function __construct(MyClass $mc)
    {
      $this->mc = $mc;
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->a->mc->b;
```

The output would be: `some string`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function __construct()
    {
       $this->b = 'some string';
       $this->a = new \SomeClass($this->b);
    }
}   

class SomeClass{

    function __construct($b) 
    {
        echo $b; // it will become a $this->b as given while creating new class in MyClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, if `MyClass::$b` ever changes it will not be reflected in the SomeClass object if done this way.

Comment: You are right :) so I think your solution might be better if he will create a new class where is not all variables set yet.